# How or can the following sql be used in an Oracle Stored procedure using parameters?

Tags: oracle

I am very new to programming Oracle SQL. Can the following sql be used in an Oracle Stored procedure using parameters (see  for where I want to use parameters)? If so, how?

```
Select Tuo.* 
 From OFFVISITS Tuo
 inner join (                   
 select mr1.pat_id, count(mr1.contact_date) 
 from OFFVISITS mr1
 inner join (                                 
   select pat_id,count(contact_date) 
   from OFFVISITS
   Where Death_Date Is Null
   A nd Rpt_Grp = <parameter 1>    
    AND MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,CONTACT_DATE) <= <parameter 2>   
   group by pat_id
   having count(contact_date) >= <parameter 3>) mr2 on mr2.pat_id = mr1.pat_id    
Where Mr1.Death_Date Is Null
And Mr1.Rpt_Grp = <parameter 4> 
AND MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,mr1.CONTACT_DATE) <= <parameter 5> 
and mr1.ref_bill_code in (select DIAGNOSIS_CODE from DIAG_CODES)
group by mr1.pat_id
Having Count(Mr1.Contact_Date) >= 1) Mr On Mr.Pat_Id = Tuo.Pat_Id  
AND TUO.RPT_GRP = <parameter 6>  
order by tuo.pat_id';
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyFirst_PROC
(
    PARAMETER_1_  IN   VARCHAR2,
    PARAMETER_4_  IN   INT,
    PARAMETER_5_  IN   DATE
)
IS
BEGIN


   ...
   Where Mr1.Death_Date Is Null
   And Mr1.Rpt_Grp = PARAMETER_4_   
   AND MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,mr1.CONTACT_DATE) <= PARAMETER_5_ 

END;
```

I have left the remaining parameters for you to fill and correct the parameter types as I had to guess what type your columns (E.g. Mr1.Rpt_Grp) are

Comment: What about parameters #2, #3 and #6 ? Any reason you left them out?

Comment: I wanted the user to fill in the rest as I had to guess the datatype for each parameter

Comment: When I add the parameters as indicated, I receive the following error when I compile the procedure using Oracle SQL Developer: Error(30,3): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement. The select statement it points to is: Select Tuo.*. Do you have any ideas what is causing this error? Also, is this still possible if I want the results to go to a table? If so, would I need to use 'execute immediate' ?

Comment: Thanks codingbiz once I setup the parameters correctly it worked.